# Font looking different on windows machine

Tags: html, css, macos, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing the website [**watr.io**](http://watr.io), and the font on windows looks different than the font on mac. The one on mac is the one I want, can anybody see what is wrong? I've been trying to fix it for hours.

Here are screenshots of comparsions

[image: Here is the mac version]

[image: Here is the windows version]

Comment: The font is not looking different. the windows machine is not using the same font. You are not loading the font correctly

Comment: Are you using Helvetica Neue?

Comment: Yes I am using Helvatica Neue

Comment: Post the code you have in your question please.

Comment: How are you loading the custom `Helvatica Neue` font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the look's of this you are using a Helvatica font.

A font that exists on Mac OS but does not on Window's

You will need to add the font to your site using `@font-face`.

But in order to do this you must own the font or you could use an alternative font.

Check this to learn a bit more about font-face http://www.font-face.com/.

Answer (score 2):

The font used must be available on the machine/server you're using, you cant just use any font. If you use a font that doesnt exist on a machine, a default will be used instead. Use some safe sonts instead 
:http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a web font, make sure that you are loading is properly. If you are not using a web font, then you are at the mercy of each system's internal fonts. For example, stating that you want a sans-serif/Helvetica/Arial font will most likely show Helvetica on a Mac and Arial on a PC.

If neither of these are the issue, please provide more details and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting your code I see the following:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Your browser first looks at the first font on the list, if the machine has it available, it uses it. If it is not available on the machine, it looks to see if you have loaded it with `@font-face` or perhaps by loading it in you `<head>` (how Google Fonts suggests). If the font is still not found, it moves on to the next font on the list. Since Macs have this font available, it uses it. Since Windows does not have it available, it ignores it and moves to the next font.

What you need to do is download the font you need and place it in a directory so that you can use it using `@font-face` in your CSS.

Comment: CodeGodie- how did you look at the code? The OP hasn't posted a link and I couldn't find that text with a web search.

Comment: He did put his website name in the OP. He just didnt hyperlink it. I just edited it. Check it out

Comment: It's amazing what a hyperlink can do. Thanks for the edit!